# How to read from console into 2 tasks without losing any input characters?

Tags: posix, stdin

In my environment with Nuttx, POSIX complaint RTOS, 2 tasks(processes) are running & both receive input from console. When "weather" is input in console, based on priority and other factors, each task receives subset of input characters.

How to get "weather" in both the tasks irrespective of the priority etc..? Currently each task wait on select followed by read on stdin.

Is there a stdin stream/buffer per process?

Answer (score 1):

Of course after a character "w" is received by one task, it cannot be received by another since it has already been consumed and is no longer available in the incoming data stream.

What you need is the moral equivalent of a tee into both tasks.  This tee task would:

1. Move the console input descriptor (0)

```
    int input;
    dup2(0, input);
    close(0);
```

2. Create two pipes.  Spawn task 1 to so that it inherits pipe1 on stdin like:

```
    int task1_fd[2];
    pipe(task1_fd);
    dup2(task1_fd[0], 0);
    if (task1_fd[0] != 0)
      close(task1_fd[0])
    task_create(...)
```

2. Spawn task 2 so that it inherits pipe2 on stdin like:

```
    int task2_fd[2];
    ... similar ...
```

2. Read from the console,

```
    nread = read(input, buf, buflen);
```

3. And write to both pipes:

```
    nwritten = write(task1_fd1[1], buf, nread);
    ...
    nwritten = write(task1_fd2[1], buf, nread);
```

In this way each character read from the console well be echoed to both tasks.

The above code examples use NuttX facilities to do the job.  The redirection could be done a little more cleanly on a full POSIX system like Linux that can support fork().

Here we did:  save the standard input file descriptor, redirect I/O, and spawn.

In a full POSIX system, you could do:  fork, redirect I/O, and exec.

Nuttx actually does support fork (well, vfork) and the exec functions.  But those are seldom used in a deeply embedded system.

Comment: If you want bi-directional communications, the answer is a little different.  In that case, you would probably want to use a NuttX Pseudo-Terminal instead of a pair of pipes.  NuttX Pseduo-Terminals are functionally equivalent to Linux Pseudo-Terminals.

Comment: What happens if some other task directly reads from stdin? Why I ask this is coz, my development is limited to kernel, what if app or other module read directly from stdin? I just want to get all input characters even if there are other consumers, it is possible?

Comment: Still the same rule applies.  It is a byte data stream.  Reading a byte removes it from the data stream and it cannot be read again.

The suggestion above works only because it duplicates the data stream, allowing the bytes to be read twice, once from each data stream.

If you want one consumer to get all of the data, starving the others, then the thing to do is to make that consumer the highet priority.  Then it will get all of the data; the others will get none.